# make changes outside angularjs view

Tags: templates, binding, routes, angularjs

i'm using Angular's Routeprovider together with ngView to make my webapp. However, the ng-view is a div inside the body of the page, but when the curent route changes, I'd also like to change the title tag, and possibly some meta tags. What would be the best way to do this? Attach another ng-controller to the html tag, and control content of title and meta tags from there using the $location service? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well This can be done easily. Without giving you the code, i'm sharing already given solution's link. http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2425-Decorating-Scope-Methods-In-The-AngularJS-Prototype-Chain.htm